# Show Clickable Icon on Link at Hover

Tags: css

First of all, I´m not very firm with CSS. I try to show an icon (right side) on my sidebar link (nav-first-level) on mouseover. The Sidebar-Link currently uses 100% of the Sidebar. Do you have a tip for me?

```
<ul>                        
<li class="nav-first-level">
    <a class="facetGroup" href="#">Cardiology<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <span class="markGroup "><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2" ></i></span>

            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">

                                <li ng-repeat="facet in cardiologyItems">
                                    <a href="#" ng-attr-title="facet.group + ': ' + facet.name" ng-click="getTitle(facet.group, facet.name)"><span>{{ facet.name }}</span></a>
                                </li>

            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your question is very confusing please try isolate WHERE you want this done and on what selector

Comment: Oh...Sorry. The selector 'markGroup, should placed over the selector 'facetGroup'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should get you there, take a **[look (show image icon on rollover with CSS)](http://jsfiddle.net/twfJh/2/)**.

---

• Swap `.image` class with your `.facetGroup` > remove `<span>` use a `<div>` and swap demo `.play` class with your .`markGroup`. *Basically follow how it's done below and customize with your selectors!*

---

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image"> <a href="#">  <img src="http://www.itsalif.info/blogfiles/video-play/vthumb.jpg" /> </a></div>
    <div class="play"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flavour/button_play_blue.png" /> </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.itemsContainer {
    background:red; 
    float:left;
    position:relative
}
.itemsContainer:hover .play{display:block}
.play{
  position : absolute;
    display:none;
    top:20%; 
    width:40px;
    margin:0 auto; left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use li:hover property.Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
ul li ul li:hover {
    list-style-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-16.png');
} 
ul li ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Cardiology
        <ul>
            <li>citem1</li>
            <li>citem2</li>
            <li>citem3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Other
        <ul>
            <li>oitem1</li>
            <li>oitem2</li>
            <li>oitem3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Working JSFiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/t41w9u2w/2/